# Reference model of application/host/gateway/network levels

Tags: network-protocols

On page 9, [RFC793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-9) describes the place of TCP in the protocol hierarchy as follows:

```
   +------+ +-----+ +-----+       +-----+
   |Telnet| | FTP | |Voice|  ...  |     |  Application Level
   +------+ +-----+ +-----+       +-----+
         |   |         |             |
        +-----+     +-----+       +-----+
        | TCP |     | RTP |  ...  |     |  Host Level
        +-----+     +-----+       +-----+
           |           |             |
        +-------------------------------+
        |    Internet Protocol & ICMP   |  Gateway Level
        +-------------------------------+
                       |
          +---------------------------+
          |   Local Network Protocol  |    Network Level
          +---------------------------+
```

**Does this reference model have a name?**

Comment: On a side note: Eight years later, [RFC1122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1122#page-8) introduced the distinction between Application/Transport/Internet/Link Layer.

Comment: That's the OSI model

Comment: Or more specifically it's the protocol hierarchy model. http://www.e-cartouche.ch/content_reg/cartouche/formats/en/html/Internet_TCP_IP.html